# How to prevent dired from changing window (frame) title?

Tags: dired, frames

Using graphical version of gnu emacs v24.4.1 on centos7.
I set the window (frame) title manually with this:

```
(setq frame-title-format '("SAMPLE TITLE"))
```

It is working OK and tittle gets set fine.
Problem is when I start (or switch) to dired it gets the title chaged from the value I set (to the folder name usually).

I am thinking about a post-hook ? I am new to emacs (just a year), so not even sure if that is possible.

Is there any way to prevent dired from changing the window title?

Comment: For future reference:
Seems like the title changes each time I reload the config with this line:
(load-file "~/.emacs")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that happening with a virgin Emacs instance: `emacs -Q`. Do you?

If you don't see it either, using `emacs -Q` to start Emacs, then recursively bisect your init file to find the code that is causing the behavior you don't like. You can use command `comment-region` to comment-out the region (or with `C-u` to uncomment it).

Comment: I am investigating why/who is changing it. First time it changed I think I was in a dired buffer, but maybe I was too fast blaming it. It is usually not changing (more than four days now with no change), but eventually something triggers a change, and after that it changes all the time (as normal). Will post here if I can get to any conclusion FTR.